# Zend_Form: how to remove multiple <legend> elements in fieldset (nested DIV)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to get something like this:

```
<div class="widgetbox">
    <legend class="widgettitle">Widget Box</legend>
    <div class="widgetcontent"> Content goes here... </div>
</div>
```

my code look like this:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(
        $fields,
        'main',
        array(
            'legend' => $this->_tlabel.'group_main',
            'decorators' => array(
                'FormElements',
                array(
                    array('widgetcontent'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'widgetcontent')
                    ),
                array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'div',  'class' => 'widgetbox')),
            )
        )
    );
```

and all I can get is:

```
<div class="widgetbox">
  <legend>Main info</legend>
    <div class="widgetcontent">
      <legend>Main info</legend>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I get double **legend** elements, but I want only one - first on, right after **div.widgetbox**.

Can you help me remove unneeded **legend** element from nested div?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? The decorators you're specifying don't include a legend/fieldset, so I don't see how you can be getting two of them. Also, I believe `<legend>` is only valid inside a `<fieldset>`, so your desired output is not valid HTML.

Comment: there is legend declaration: `'legend' => $this->_tlabel.'group_main',`

Comment: OK, I know it won't be valid and I can live with that for now. Ideally would be to replace <legend> with for example <h4> but I guess it's beyond Zend_Form capabilities :/

Comment: also when I included 'Fieldset' -> I got 3 <legend> elements ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use an `h4` instead, but not as a legend. Try:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(
    $fields,
    'main',
    array(
        'description' => 'Widget title',
        'decorators' => array(
            'FormElements',
            array(array('widgetcontent' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'widgetcontent')),
            array('Description', array('tag' => 'h4', 'placement' => 'prepend', 'class' => 'widgettitle')),
            array(array('widgetbox' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div',  'class' => 'widgetbox'))
        )
    )
);
```

This adds a description decorator and sets its tag as `<h4>`. I also aliased the widgetbox decorator to make it clearer how it all fits together. This gives me:

```
<div class="widgetbox">
    <h4 class="widgettitle">Widget title</h4>
    <div class="widgetcontent">...</div>
</div>
```

Like I said in my comment, since your code doesn't include a fieldset decorator, I don't see how what you've posted could include any legends at all, so it seems like there's something elsewhere in your app that's changing the decorators after this runs. If you're still getting legends, you need to try and figure out where they are being added.